# How to read device spec from the HttpContext with .NET6

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, httprequest, .net-6.0

I have an old project in .NET Framework where I read the client specification from the `HttpContext` from the Request in an API/Website.

I tried to migrate this function in .NET6 but I can't find any of the properties I expected like `Browser`, `Remote IP`, `MobileDeviceModel` and so on. This is the function.

```
public static string CheckParameter(this HttpContext hc, string paramName)
{
    string rtn = "";

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(hc.Request[paramName]))
        rtn = hc.Request[paramName];

    return rtn;
}

public StatDetail ExtractUserDetails(HttpContextBase hc)
{
    ud.TrackElement = trackElement;
    ud.TrackElementType = trackElementType;

    HttpBrowserCapabilitiesBase browse = hc.Request.Browser;

    string platform = os.Platform(hc.Request.UserAgent);
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(platform))
        platform = browse.Platform;

    ud.Platform = platform;
    ud.IsMobile = browse.IsMobileDevice;
    ud.ISCrawler = browse.Crawler;
    ud.JScriptVersion = browse.JScriptVersion.ToString();
    ud.MobileDeviceModel = browse.MobileDeviceModel;
    ud.MobileDeviceManufacturer = browse.MobileDeviceManufacturer;
    ud.ScreenPixelsHeight = browse.ScreenPixelsHeight.ToString();
    ud.ScreenPixelsWidth = browse.ScreenPixelsWidth.ToString();
    ud.IP = hc.Request.UserHostAddress;
    ud.Url = hc.Request.Url.ToString();
    ud.userAgent = hc.Request.UserAgent;

    if (hc.Request.UrlReferrer != null)
        ud.Referrer = hc.Request.UrlReferrer.ToString();

    return ud;
}
```

In my project I added

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
```

and injected in the constructor of the Api.

How can I obtain those values with .NET6?

Comment: Server-side browser detection has never worked reliably, and has [caused serious problems in the past](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/bug-and-fix-aspnet-fails-to-detect-ie10-causing-dopostback-is-undefined-javascript-error-or-maintain-ff5-scrollbar-position). I would seriously hope it's *not* available in ASP.NET Core / 5 / 6. :)

Comment: To understand why it's so unreliable, I would recommend reading [WebAIM: History of the browser user-agent string](https://webaim.org/blog/user-agent-string-history/). Then remember that this article was posted 12 years ago, and imagine how much more complicated user-agent strings are today.